# Display or print loop variable for debugging purposes

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, stata, display

```
ID  A1  A2  A3
1001    ABD AAA ABC
1002    ABE BBB CCC
1003    ABC CCC DDD
```

I have a loop as follows:

```
generate trackr = 0
display "generated trackr"
foreach var of varlist a1 a2 a3{
    display "`var'" id[_n]
    replace trackr = 1 if (`var'=="ABC")
}
```

In Stata, I would like to find out and print when a change has been made to `trackr`. (I want to find out in which row/column "ABC" was discovered.)

I tried the above `id[_n]` and it works only partially.

I would like to display `id[_n]` ONLY `if var=="ABC"` and `trackr` changes to 1 (from 0).  I tried putting everything in an `if` block, but I think `if` in Stata works differently?

Comment: The wording `"bonus" is good for a teacher challenging students, not for students asking a teacher!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop for what you appear to want. See `dataex` from SSC for a better way to give example data in Stata questions.

```
clear
input ID  str3 (A1  A2  A3) 
1001    ABD AAA ABC
1002    ABE BBB CCC
1003    ABC CCC DDD
end 

gen trackr = inlist("ABC", A1, A2, A3) 
list if inlist("ABC", A1, A2, A3) 

     +---------------------------------+
     |   ID    A1    A2    A3   trackr |
     |---------------------------------|
  1. | 1001   ABD   AAA   ABC        1 |
  3. | 1003   ABC   CCC   DDD        1 |
     +---------------------------------+
```

Here `inlist()` yields 1 if any of the second and later arguments is equal to the first argument and 0 otherwise.

In your loop something like `display A1[_n]` will only show values in the first observation, as you loop over variables, but not observations. But no loop is needed.

If you wish to see just the first observation that satisfies your criterion, one way to do that is

```
. list if trackr & sum(trackr) == 1

     +---------------------------------+
     |   ID    A1    A2    A3   trackr |
     |---------------------------------|
  1. | 1001   ABD   AAA   ABC        1 |
     +---------------------------------+
```

and it follows that `list if sum(inlist("ABC", A1, A2, A3)) == 1` would also work to find the first such observation.

Comment: Thanks Prof. Cox, this will work perfectly!  Will look into dataex for posting examples in the future.

Comment: I guess when I go through Stata documentation, I sometimes don't even know what function(s) to look for that may be exactly what I need.  In this case, it was inlist().  The last time you pointed me to bysort (which maps somewhat to groupby).  If I wanted to perform more database-like operations starting with intersections (2 vectors) to more complex inner and outer joins, where would I begin to investigate these?  In other words, is there a glossary that maps out Stata functions to commonly-used/known paradigms from other languages (and vice versa)?

Comment: Conversely, I didn't know that `groupby` in some language you don't state is roughly the same as `bysort` in Stata except that you tell me that it is. But what you want is Stata translations of terms that are familiar to you, and while I sympathise I don't know that any such glossary exists. There is one book on R for Stata users but neither author is, or was, really authoritative about Stata, and I've never read it, and I don't know how useful it might be for reverse engineering. The positive advice is to skim manual sections that might be relevant such as data management or functions.

Comment: Thanks Prof. Cox.  I have a data set with 100's of columns that have similar strings (ABC, DEF, AAC etc.).  Your inline() solution already lets me know that the string exists in that specific row.  However, instead of the "1" in the tracker, can the column number in which the string was discovered in that row be displayed.  That way I can can zoom in on that specific row and column while debugging. PS: Group By was from SQL (which I am a bit more comfortable with).

Comment: I suggest you edit your question using realistic variable names for this version.